# When using minted to insert code snippets, the wrong snippet can be inserted

Tags: minted

I'm writing a project where I need to include snippets of code from old git commits. I'm using a Python script to pre-process my LaTeX source code and convert

```latex
%: 37e7c208a33d7cbbc8e0bb6c94cd889e2918c605
%: src/lintrans/gui/main_window.py:229-235
```

into a `minted` environment with code taken from that file in that commit, between those line numbers, like so:

```latex
{
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{
    \ttfamily
    \textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1}{
        \footnotesize
        \oldstylenums{
            \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=-3\else
            \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=-2\else
            \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=-1
                \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{228}
            \else
            \arabic{FancyVerbLine}
            \fi\fi\fi
        }
    }
}
\begin{minted}[firstnumber=-3]{python}
# 37e7c208a33d7cbbc8e0bb6c94cd889e2918c605
# src/lintrans/gui/main_window.py

    def render_expression(self) -> None:
        """Render the expression in the input box, and then clear the box."""
        self.plot.transform_by_matrix(
            self.matrix_wrapper.evaluate_expression(
                self.lineedit_expression_box.text()
            )
        )
\end{minted}
}
```

It looks like this when rendered:
[image: output example]

I'm redefining `\theFancyVerbLine` to do custom line numbers. The first three lines are uninportant, so they get no line numbers, and then we start from the actually desired line number.

The preprocessor converts `development.tex` into `process_development.tex`, which is then included in `main.tex` using `\subfile{sections/processed_development.tex}`.

This all works fine. However, I end up with lots of `minted` environments and for some bizarre reason, the 27th one is a copy of the 1st, and the 28th is a copy of the 2nd. The 29th and onward are all fine.

The preprocessing is working as intended, and the correct code snippets are being included in the source, but for some reason, when I compile with `latexmk -lualatex` like normal, these code snippets don't work properly. It's only the 27th and 28th. Out of 32 `minted` environments all defined like this in their own scope with their own `\theFancyVerbLine` definition, only these two are broken.

I have no idea why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=-3\else`  should be `\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=-3 \else` otherwise you will always expand the else branch before doing the test. (other numbers similarly need to be terminated by space)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would `\relax` help here? That would be easier to spot than a space.

Comment: @daleif `\relax` is possibly OK but you need to check the context whereas a space is always OK. so (since I didn't read the rest of the code)  space was a safer suggestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was an issue with the `_minted-main` directory. After deleting this directory and re-compiling, it compiled as expected.

I don't know why this was happening. I can only assume it was a caching issue, but deleting the folder fixed it.